# angular ui directive not binding to data loaded using $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, directive, ngresource

I am trying to build an angularjs app that is loading data using `$resource` and provides pagination using `pagination` directive from angular ui bootstrap (`http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/`).
The pagination directive template html is rendered. It reacts if I try to set its parameters like current page or max pages manually (e.g. `$scope.TotalResult = 20;`). But when the data is loaded using `$resource` pagination doesn't update (e.g. doesn't change number of pages). Seems like it doesn't bind to the scope.

HTML:
    
    
        
        Find

```
<div>
    <p>Total pages: {{ TotalPages }} | Total in Dbase: {{ TotalResults }} </p>

    <!--paginator-->


    <pagination total-items="TotalResults" ng-model="pageFilter" 
        items-per-page="10" ng-change="updateData()">
    </pagination>

    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in Results">
            <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-10">
                <a href="#/employees/{{ item.Id }}">
                    <h3>{{ item.Name }}<span class="badge">{{ item.Rating }}</span></h3>
                </a>

                <h4>Commments : {{ item.CommentsCount }} </h4>

                <p>{{ item.Description }}</p>
            </div>
</div>
</li>
    </ul>
```

JS:
app.controller('EmployeeListController', function ($scope, $resource) {

```
var Empl = $resource('api/insects', { name: '@name', page: '@page' });

var updateData = function () {
    Empl.get({ name: $scope.nameFilter, page: $scope.pageFilter - 1 }, function (data) {
        $scope.Results = data.Results;
        $scope.TotalPages = data.TotalPages;
        $scope.TotalResults = data.TotalResults;
    });
};

$scope.updateData = updateData;

updateData();
```

});

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is TotalPages initialized before updateData is called? (when page loads)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when u call $resource(...).get, u recieve special object with 'promise', so angular knows that it will change sets and up listeners for that, same is true for 'data', but it is not true for data.Results, which is usual object.

so this should work:

```
Empl.get({ name: $scope.nameFilter, page: $scope.pageFilter - 1 }, function (data) {
    $scope.data = data;
});

<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in data.Results">
```

(I prefer to write: `$scope.data = Empl.get({ name: $scope.nameFilter, page: $scope.pageFilter - 1 });`)